# How/where to get endorsed?

Tags: work-experience, references

I'm successfully finishing a project on a difficult technology that I want to be known for. How/where to get endorsed for this?

The only place I can think of is LinkedIn, but I'm not very active there.

I don't have a website where I quote my clients.

My client is happy with my work. I'm pretty sure he won't turn me down when I ask. But i don't know what to ask for. 
My client is remote-- on the other side of the Globe if this is any relevant.

How do you show work-done? What ways are out there?

Comment: Do it through LinkedIn. If it's done any other way, it's not really believable. On your own web site, you could post anything you want. There is nothing stopping you from lying.

Comment: What does TIA mean?

Comment: @guest - thx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LinkedIn endorsements exist but are pretty much worthless.  Everyone in your contact list gets prompted regularly to endorse you for something so everyone ends up with tons of endorsements many of which make extremely little sense.  Dozens of people have endorsed me for skills that I barely have or that I wasn't doing when I worked with them.

LinkedIn recommendations are a bit more useful since they require someone to spend some actual time composing a few sentences.  On the other hand, plenty of people game the system by trading recommendations (A recommends B, B recommends C, C recommends A) so it doesn't mean much.

You can ask your client if they'd be willing to be a reference for you if a future potential client wants to talk to a happy customer.  That may be valuable for some potential clients but it requires some ongoing effort to maintain the relationship.

If you want to be known for a particular technology, though, none of these things are likely to be particularly helpful to you.  It's generally going to be much more useful to show your knowledge, not to have someone else talk about your knowledge.  Post articles about things you learned about the technology.  Answer questions about it on StackOverflow.  Get involved with a user group or some other community related to the technology.  That's more work, of course, but it is much more effective in getting known for a particular technology.